# MS Excel query for if else condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel sheet with columns - paid, Bal, total, and grand total,
So, I want to make a if else statement like
If( paid have value AND total have value) then total is store in grand total,
Else if( paid have value AND total don't have value) then paid is final value in grand total

Please suggest simple statement for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(AND(Paid <>"",Total<>""),Paid+Total,AND(Paid<>"",Total = ""),Paid)`

You can enter this formula into the Grand Total column, replacing "total", and "paid" with the appropriate cell references.

If this helps, please click the checkmark to accept the answer.